# Xamarin Plugin Geolocator not working on Xamarin Forms android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I have installed the following nuget:

- Xamarin.Forms.Maps Version => 3.1.0.697729
- Plugin.CurrentActivity => 2.1.0.4
- Xam.Plugin.Geolocator => 4.5.0.6
- Plugin.Permissions => 3.0.0.12

I have the following class:

```
    public class MainApplication : Application
    {
         public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnershiptranser): base(handle, transer)
         {
         }

         public override void OnCreate()
         {
               base.OnCreate();
               CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this);
         }
    }
```

I have the code in my MainActivity class:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Android manifest

```
<application android:label="MyApp.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY " android:value="AIza..." />
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Android manifest - permission

- < uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
- < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
- < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"
  />
- < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
- < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
- < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
  />
- < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

I try use **meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"** 
instead of **meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"**

Also adding this line below < meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

I have one View where I have my map:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <maps:Map x:Name="Map" />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And the code behind:

```
    private async Task LoadMap()
    {
        if (await Utils.Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Location))
        {
            var currentLocation = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            // MORE CODE
        }

    }
```

And I use this class https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/blob/master/samples/PermissionsSample/PermissionsSample/Utils.cs for ask the permission

I get the api key from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup?hl=en (Maps SDK for Android)

The version of my Xamarin Forms is 3.1.0.697729

I have created another project empty and the location on android is still not working.

In iOS I have no problem. The location is working.

I read this, https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html.

When I run the app and the next line of code try to execute the method, it no longer executes the following lines of the method.The application works, but do not skip any exceptions.

```
   await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

This line does not return anything.

Any idea why it fails?

Comment: How do you call `LoadMap`?

Comment: @Cheesebaron In my code behind                                                               public MapLocal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin>();

            MoveMapToCurrentPosition();
        }

Comment: put this line of code `Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);` in your **MainActivity.cs`** . any changes?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the LoadMap call. If GetPositionAsync doesn't return you have a deadlock

Comment: @Fuong Nothing, the same result if I have CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle); or not

Comment: I have started using Xamarin.Essentials because many of these Xamarin plugins are moving towards it https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials . Take a look at the geolocation documentation and consider using it because probably has better support https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/essentials/geolocation

Comment: @Cheesebaron How can I see that? ( deadlock )

Comment: @JorgeMHT, if you read **Permissions & Additional Setup Considerations** section in [GeolocatoPlugin]( https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html) you must at least have that line of code in your MainActivity.cs for Android

Comment: @Fuong I have this method OnRequestPermissionsResult in my MainActivity

Comment: @J.Aguilar At the moment I can add this plugins in my project